# dspace command line import files not appearing in collection

Tags: command-line, dspace

I am running dspace 6.1 on Suse 12.2.  I have used the command line import command to bring files into a collection, and the command prints out that it succeeded.

```
bin/dspace import --add --eperson=myemail@mycompany.com --
collection=123456789/49 --source=/opt/dspace/import_dateien/test/ --
mapfile=mapfile
Destination collections:
Owning  Collection: 1982-11-10 Collection
Adding items from directory: /opt/dspace/import_dateien/test/
Generating mapfile: mapfile
Started: 1503332092481
Ended: 1503332095888
Elapsed time: 3 secs (3407 msecs)
```

I have added files without additional metadata, and no SAF zip file, because I want the extra files in the collection without their own metadata, only the existing set of metadata.

The name of the collection is correct in the success message.  But I do not see the files in the collection.  Are they there, but hidden?  How can I get them to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the command found zero items in the batch.  You should see several lines of output for each item.

The first thing I would check is that the source directory "/opt/dspace/import_dateien/test/" conforms to SAF:  it should contain numbered subdirectories, each containing one item.  The importer seems to find no directories there.

Comment: Thanks very much @Mark Wood for your answer!  You seem to be saying that the import command accepts only SAF files, and not ordinary files.  In the jspui interface, I can add files to a collection without adding an extra line of metadata.  This way we have one set of metadata and several files.  We need this functionality on the command line, since we have several thousand files to import.  Is there a way to do this on the command line?  Or is there a way to use the SAF without being forced to add a metadata line for each file?  I would happily use the SAF if that were possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! I was using SAFBuilder, and there one has a csv file, with one line per file, each file with metadata. But, the SAFBuilder script creates a folder as well as a zip file, and in this folder are the files, a text file named contents, and the metadata as xml. One can simply add here the extra files one wants to add, list them in the contents file, and re-zip it. I just tested it with bin/dspace import, and there are my extra files in the collection. As @Mark Wood said, my files were listed in the output from the script.